# Conditional template return type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, types, matrix, return

I declared a templated `Matrix` class this way:

```
template<typename Type> class Matrix {
   // Some code for matrix computations
}
```

Now, I'm trying to overload the `operator+` in a way that guarantees that the larger Type will be the result. I was trying this thing:

```
template<typename OtherType> 
Matrix<Type> operator+ (Matrix<OtherType> mat) {
    // Dimension check and matrix addition code
}
```

But doing that, I would practically force C++ to choose `Matrix<Type>` as the return type. What I want to achieve is that, for instance, `Matrix<int>` + `Matrix<float>` will result in `Matrix<float>`.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: `float`s cannot store every `int` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a compile-time conditional:

```
template<
    typename OtherType,
    typename T = typename std::conditional<(sizeof(Type) <= sizeof(OtherType)),
                    OtherType, Type>::type
>
Matrix<T> operator+ (const Matrix<OtherType>& mat);
```

or use the C++11 feature`decltype` to deduce the type:

```
template<typename OtherType>
auto operator+ (const Matrix<OtherType>& mat)
    -> Matrix<decltype(std::declval<OtherType>() + std::declval<Type>())>;
```

Comment: Note that doing it with sizeof is a bit strange, because whether it chooses int64_t or double (likewise int32_t or float) will depend on which argument is on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 3):

You can model this problem on this simplified example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::common_type<T, U>::type add(T x, U y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto add(T x, U y) -> decltype(x + y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

The two solutions aren't exactly the same in general, but should be for elementary arithmetic operations.

Comment: Well, `Matrix<T> const& x, Matrix <U> const& y) -> Matrix< decltype( x(0,0) + y(0,0)) >`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a mapping describing which type should be chosen for a given combination of types. For example (just done for floating point types; it could be extended, of course):

```
template <typename, typename> struct best_type;
template <typename T> struct best_type<T, T> { typedef T type; };
template <> best_type<float, double> { typdef double type; };
template <> best_type<double, float> { typdef double type; };
template <> best_type<float, long double> { typdef long double type; };
template <> best_type<long double, float> { typdef long double type; };
template <> best_type<double, long double> { typdef long double type; };
template <> best_type<long double, double> { typdef long double type; };


template <typename T0, typename T1>
Matrix<typename best_type<T0, T1>::type>
operator+ (Matrix<T0> const& m0, Matrix<T1> const& m1) {
    // ...
}
```

The `operator+()` is formulated as non-member but it can, as well be a member (normally it works better for `operator+()` to be a non-member potentially delegating to a member `operator+=()`).